# Why is there a version mismatch between my docker-compose.yml and the docker-compose.override.yml?

Tags: docker

I am going through the tutorial, https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html and am on step 7.  When I run the command, `.\up.ps1`,  I get an error `Version mismatch: file .\docker-compose.yml specifies version 1 but extension file .\docker-compose.override.yml uses version 2.2`.  I opened both files and do not see a version number in the docker-compose.yml file.  I changed the version within the .\docker-compose.override.yml to version 1 but then got an error, version in .\docker-compose.ovrride.yml is invalid.  I think I need to change the version of the docker-compose.yml to be verison 2.4 but do not see a way to do that...This is what I have in the docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
  traefik:
    isolation: ${TRAEFIK_ISOLATION}
    image: ${TRAEFIK_IMAGE}
    command:
      - "--ping"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--providers.file.directory=C:/etc/traefik/config/dynamic"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.forwardedHeaders.insecure"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8079:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping"]
    volumes:
      - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        type: npipe
      - ./traefik:C:/etc/traefik
    depends_on:
      id:
        condition: service_healthy
      cm:
        condition: service_healthy
  mssql:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}nonproduction/mssql-developer:2017-${SITECORE_VERSION}
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: ${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "14330:1433"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .\mssql-data
        target: c:\data
  mssql-init:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp1-mssql-init:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    environment:
      SQL_SERVER: ${SQL_SERVER}
      SQL_ADMIN_LOGIN: ${SQL_SA_LOGIN}
      SQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      SITECORE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${SITECORE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      POST_DEPLOYMENT_WAIT_PERIOD: 300
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "if ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('DatabasesDeploymentStatus', 'Machine') -eq 'Complete') { exit 0 } else { exit 1}"]
      start_period: 300s
      interval: 5s
    depends_on:
      mssql:
        condition: service_healthy
  solr:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}nonproduction/solr:8.8.2-${SITECORE_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "8984:8983"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .\solr-data
        target: c:\data
    environment:
      SOLR_MODE: solrcloud
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "try { $$statusCode = (iwr http://solr:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS -UseBasicParsing).StatusCode; if ($$statusCode -eq 200) { exit 0 } else { exit 1} } catch { exit 1 }"]
  solr-init:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-solr-init:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    environment:
      SITECORE_SOLR_CONNECTION_STRING: http://solr:8983/solr
      SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME: ${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}
    depends_on:
      solr:
        condition: service_healthy
  id:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-id6:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    environment:
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__SitecoreMemberShipOptions__ConnectionString: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Core;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__AccountOptions__PasswordRecoveryUrl: https://${CM_HOST}/sitecore/login?rc=1
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__PasswordClient__ClientSecrets__ClientSecret1: ${SITECORE_IDSECRET}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__DefaultClient__AllowedCorsOrigins__AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1: https://${CM_HOST}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateRawData: ${SITECORE_ID_CERTIFICATE}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__PublicOrigin: https://${ID_HOST}
      Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateRawDataPassword: ${SITECORE_ID_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pwsh", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
      timeout: 300s
    depends_on:
      mssql-init:
        condition: service_healthy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.id-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.id-secure.rule=Host(`${ID_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.id-secure.tls=true"
  cm:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cm:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      id:
        condition: service_started
      xconnect:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Core: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Core;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Security: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Core;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Master: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Master;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Web: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Web;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Messaging;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Pools: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.pools;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Referencedata;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Tasks: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.tasks;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_ExperienceForms: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.ExperienceForms;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Exm.Master: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Exm.master;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Reporting: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Reporting;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Sitecore.Reporting.Client: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Cortex.Processing.Engine: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Solr.Search: http://solr:8983/solr;solrCloud=true
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SitecoreIdentity.Secret:  ${SITECORE_IDSECRET}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Operations.Client: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Reporting.Client: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.ReferenceData.Client: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
      Sitecore_Identity_Server_Authority: https://${ID_HOST}
      Sitecore_Identity_Server_InternalAuthority: http://id
      Sitecore_Identity_Server_CallbackAuthority: https://${CM_HOST}
      Sitecore_Identity_Server_Require_Https: "false"
      Sitecore_Analytics_Forwarded_Request_Http_Header: X-Forwarded-For
      SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME: ${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}
      MEDIA_REQUEST_PROTECTION_SHARED_SECRET: ${MEDIA_REQUEST_PROTECTION_SHARED_SECRET}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
      timeout: 300s
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.force-STS-Header.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.force-STS-Header.headers.stsSeconds=31536000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.rule=Host(`${CM_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.cm-secure.middlewares=force-STS-Header"
  xconnect:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xconnect:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    depends_on:
      mssql-init:
        condition: service_healthy
      solr-init:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Messaging;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Storage: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Storage;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Tasks: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Tasks;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Reporting: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Reporting;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Marketingautomation: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Marketingautomation;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Pools: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.pools;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Referencedata;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Collection: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SolrCore: http://solr:8983/solr/${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}_xdb;solrCloud=true
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:CollectionSearch:Services:Solr.SolrReaderSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:CollectionSearch:Services:XConnectSolrHealthCheckServicesConfiguration:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrReaderSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrWriterSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
      timeout: 300s
  xdbsearchworker:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xdbsearchworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      xconnect:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Collection: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SolrCore: http://solr:8983/solr/${SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME}_xdb;solrCloud=true
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrReaderSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:SearchIndexer:Services:Solr.SolrWriterSettings:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
      Sitecore_Sitecore:XConnect:CollectionSearch:Services:XConnectSolrHealthCheckServicesConfiguration:Options:RequireHttps: 'false'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1 -Port 8080"]
      timeout: 300s
  xdbautomationworker:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-xdbautomationworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      xconnect:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Marketingautomation: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Marketingautomation;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Referencedata;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Messaging: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Messaging;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1 -Port 8080"]
      timeout: 300s
  cortexprocessingworker:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cortexprocessingworker:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      xconnect:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Storage: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Storage;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Processing.Engine.Tasks: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Tasks;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Configuration: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Search: http://xconnect
      Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Reporting: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Reporting;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}
      Sitecore_License: ${SITECORE_LICENSE}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1 -Port 8080"]
      timeout: 300s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to add on line one a version number, it'll default to version 1 if not present.  Ex.

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  traefik:
```

(obviously truncating the rest of the document).

Here's a sample of a Docker Compose file (for reference): https://github.com/Sitecore/container-deployment/blob/master/compose/sxp/10.0/ltsc2019/xp0/docker-compose.yml